# Wifi range extender with Raspberry Pi and Rasbmc

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, bridge, raspbmc

What I want to achieve is to extend the range of my Wifi to another room. I've got a router, a Raspberry pi connected to this router through a UTP cable and i've got a Wifi USB stick in the RPi.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to connect to the Wifi and have internet access in either room and also be able to connect to the RPi as well (I.E. ssh or webserver).

I've been following some setups and I've almost achieved what I want to do. I can connect to the wireless and have internet access, however I'm unable to access my RPi. The RPi itself also does not have a internet connection. How can I fix this issue?

What I'm executing to get a bridged internet connection is:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 wlan0
ip link set up dev br0
brctl addif br0 wlan0
hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

The file hostapd.conf contains:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
bridge=br0
ssid=Test
channel=1
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=Secret
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
```

Network Manager is running with the following settings:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:c4:6e:1f:20:9d:91
```

Sources I've followed:

- [Source 1](http://www.daveconroy.com/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-edimax-nano-usb-ew-7811un-rtl8188cus-chipset/)
- [Source 2](http://bogeskov.dk/UsbAccessPoint.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing more research I found a solution. I've changed the NetworkManager configuration to block the ethernet connection as well.

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:c4:6e:1f:20:9d:91;mac:ot:hr:ma:ca:dd:rs
```

I've added the following to my sequence of commands.

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
dhclient br0
```

I'm not sure why this works, but it does for me. The solution is similar to the answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/520172/wired-to-wireless-bridge-in-linux) question.

Comment: Please click the checkmark next to your answer to accept it as the solution so this question can be considered resolved.